# enabling and disabling the fields

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function which works fine but only thing, i have two tr with id when one is active, the other is hissed and if the other is active, the first one is hidden

So here it is:

```
function submitSQLForm( which ) {
                theForm = document.forms[which];
                if(!theForm.textarea1.value.length) { 
                    alert('hello');
                    console.log(!theForm.textarea1.value.length);
                    document.form_sql.textarea1.focus(); 
                    return false;
                }
                else {

                    theForm.target = (theForm.resulttarget.checked) ? '_blank' : 'execbottom'; 
                    theForm.action = (theForm.resulttarget.checked) ? theForm.action + '&nnw=1' : theForm.action;
                    theForm.submit();
                }
            }
```

now the issue is, one div has `textarea1`, and other div has textarea named as `textarea2`, i want to form to detect the textarea based upon the active div and use that textarea instead of hardcoding the value, what way i should try

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```js
var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
  form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
  inp1 = form1.querySelector("input"),
  inp2 = form2.querySelector("input"),
  check = document.querySelector("input[type='checkbox']"),
  saveButton = document.querySelector("button"),
  visibleForm = 1;

check.onchange = function() {
  form1.classList.toggle("hidden");
  form2.classList.toggle("hidden");
  visibleForm = this.checked && 1 || 2;
}

saveButton.onclick = function() {
  console.log([inp1, inp2][visibleForm - 1].value);
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked> Check/Uncheck to switch forms for testing

<form id="f1">
  Form1
  <input type="text" value="Hi from f1">
</form>

<form id="f2" class="hidden">
  Form2
  <input type="text" value="Hi from f2">
</form>

<button>Save</button>
```